# Media Foundation can not detect capture devices

Tags: visual-studio-2012, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

HRESULT MFEnumDeviceSources(*In*   IMFAttributes *pAttributes, *Out*  IMFActivate ***pppSourceActivate,
  *Out*  UINT32 *pcSourceActivate);

At Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 platform, and use this function but pcSourceActivate  return 0 and
pppSourceActivate is null.But actually machine has 9 video capture cards.Anyone help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Media Foundation supports a sub-range of what is known to be a video capture device in Windows. Perhaps the ones you have don't have support in Media Foundation.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700134#Live_Sources):

> Starting in Windows 7, Media Foundation automatically supports audio
>   and video capture devices.For video, the device must provide a kernel
>   streaming (KS) minidriver in the video capture category. Media
>   Foundation uses the PnP path to enumerate the device. For audio, Media
>   Foundation uses the Windows Multimedia Device (MMDevice) API to
>   enumerate audio endpoint devices. If the device meets these criteria,
>   there is no need to implement a custom media source.

The easiest way to tell if MS supports specific device is to use [TopoEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool from SDK to see if it lists the devices.